# Layout is not adjusting when keyboard opens up in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

This is really simple code in react-native and I am using expo.
Then keyboard opens up it covers the textinput which is not desired feature can anyone help me why? It seems to work in pure react-native.

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";

class Logins extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding" enabled>
        <TextInput placeholder="Password" style={styles.textinputstyle} />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 450,
  },textinputstyle:{
    fontSize:25,
    color:"red",
    paddingBottom:10,
  }
});

export default Logins;
```

[Here](https://snack.expo.io/@reyanshmishra/tabnavigators-issue) is the link to snack.

Answer (score 1):

Why "paddingTop: 450"? It is doing keyboard cannot opens up it covers the textinput.

```
 render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
       <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View style={{height:450}} ></View>
             <TextInput placeholder="Password last" style={styles.textinputstyle} />
       </ScrollView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
```

[Expo snack link](https://snack.expo.io/ByVHZDH0z)

Answer (score 0):

I've had good results with [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view).